# Symbol mapping is not injective

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $a(x,y,\eta) \in S_{\rho,\delta}^m(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$, in other words $a$ is a symbol in a Hörmander symbol class. Why is the symbol mapping

$$a \mapsto \text{op}\ a$$

not injective, whereby

$$(\text{op} )(u(x)) = c \iint e^{i(x-y)\eta} a(x,y,\eta) u(y) dy d\eta$$

for $u\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$? So, given one symbol $a(x,y,\eta)$, how can I find another one, $\tilde{a}$, such that $(\text{op} a)(u(x))=(\text{op} \tilde{a})(u(x))$ and $a\neq\tilde{a}$?

If $a$ depends either on $x$, $\eta$ or $y$, $\eta$ I can show that the corresponding symbol mapping is injective.